# Working with WordPress header.php - how do I generate <link> alternate dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have got two websites, one in WordPress and the other is SPA HTML + jQueryMobile.

I read this article from Google:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details#separateurls

It speaks about maintaining connected both websites because they are the same. It changes, just the type mobile and desktop.

For the mobile side, no problem because on every HTML page I put the `<link canonical>` as Google says in each single `<head>` tag, but on the desktop version I have got a WordPress website so I have the `haeder.php` that it comes up in every HTML, because it is dynamic, so how can I write dynamically within the `<header>` the tag `<link alternate >` checking the page just loaded and put the right link?

So if I put this <link> hard coded in my header.php,

```
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="http://www.example.com/Mobile/pageexample.html" >
```

I will get the same link in all my PHP pages, but I want to make it dynamic. If I am opening the page1_Desktop_Version.php, I want to write on the fly:

```
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="http://www.example.com/Mobile/page1_mobile_version.html" >
```

The first idea I had was to use jQuery, but I googled until now for a day everywhere without any luck. Is there any documentation on that?

I just found this but it works just for tag `<a>`:

```
$('#yourElementId').attr('title', 'your new title');
```

but in my case the tag <link> doesn't have an ID attribute, this is tricky. How can I fix it?

Could the following work fine? But I need to write an "if" statement for each page that has got a correspondence with the mobile site.

```
<head>
    <link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="<?php CheckAlternate(); ?>" >
</head>

<?php
    function CheckAlternate(){
        if strstr(curPageURL,"page2")
        return "www.example.com/Mobile/MobilePage2.html"
    }

    function curPageURL() {
        $pageURL = 'http';
        if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
            $pageURL .= "s";
        }
        $pageURL .= "://";
        if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }
        else {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }
        return $pageURL;
    }
?>
```

In this way the client makes a request and the response contain already the correct tag `<link rel="alternate"`. Could this be right?

I am trying this solution, but there is still a little issue:

```
<head>
    -- HTML code--

    <?php  echo checkAlternate();  ?>

        -- HTML Code--

    <?php
        function checkAlternate(){
            $sBaseLinkAlternate = "<link rel='alternate' media='only screen and (max-width: 640px)' href='";
            $sPaginaAttuale = curPageURL();

            switch ($sPaginaAttuale) {
                case "http://www.example.com/home/":
                    return htmlspecialchars($sBaseLinkAlternate) . "http://www.example.com/Mobile/home.html'>";
                    break;
            }
        }//end checkAlternate--
    ?>
<head>
```

---

Everything is perfect. This is the solution for those who are interested in it, but now I see the HTML printed in my page as text. Why? should I convert the HTML special characters in ASCII characters to be rendered as HTML code and not simple text?

Comment: I have found the solution read the Edit 2 but there is still a little issue, how to print HTML code instead of simple test in php code. thank you

Comment: Solved, it is enough to remove the "htmlspecialchars("  from the following code $sBaseLinkAlternate."http://www.example.com/Mobile/home.html'>";